# JavaScript Compiler

Tags: javascript, npm, dependencies

Im trying to compile the JS code from textarea and get output of this code, im tried used `eval()`, but not get full response. How to i can compile the JS Code from string and get the full response ? (Like playcode.io)

Comment: What does "not get full response" mean?

Comment: Eg: if i run and loop and each iteration i run console.log, only the last log has outputed

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a Function constructor

**But be careful with XSS attacks**

```
const code = 'Math.abs(-1)';
const result = new Function('', 'return (' + code + ')')();

console.log(result) // 1
```

Also you can pass parameters by arguments using first string

```
const code = 'Math.abs(someNumber)';
const runCode = new Function('someNumber', 'return (' + code + ')');

runCode(-1);
```

Comment: MDN doc here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function

Comment: Also you can make some iframe element and inject inline JS by script tags. If you choose this way it will allow you to add styles and html dynamically

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @ChristianCury Can you share an example of your code?